# Creating read-only properties in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, readonly

Many library classes in AS3 have "read only" properties. Is it possible to create such properties in custom as3 classes? In other words, I want to create a property with a public read but a private set without having to create a complex getter/setter system for every property I want to expose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to have a read only is to use the built-in `get` and `set` functions of AS3.

**Edit:**  original code was write only. For read only just use `get` instead of `set` like so:

```
package
{

import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TestClass extends Sprite
{
    private var _foo:int = 5;

    public function TestClass() {}

    public function get foo():int{ return _foo; }
    public function incrementFoo():void { _foo++; }
}

}
```

Which allows you to access foo like so:

```
var tc:TestClass = new TestClass();
trace(tc.foo);

tc.incrementFoo();
trace(tc.foo);
```

---

Here is the original for reference on write only:

```
package
{

import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TestClass extends Sprite
{
    private var _foo:int;

    public function TestClass() {}

    public function set foo(val:int):void{ _foo = val; }
}

}
```

That will allow you to set the value of _foo externally like so:

```
var tc:TestClass = new TestClass();
tc.foo = 5;

// both of these will fail
tc._foo = 6;
var test:int = tc.foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have public set and private get with the same name. But as James showed, you can rename the setter into something else and make it private to get a read only property.

Answer (score 1):

Well can't you do like this?

```
package
{

import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TestClass extends Sprite
{
    private var _foo:int = 5;

    public function TestClass() {}

    public function get foo():int{ return _foo; }
    public function set foo(value:int):void{ throw new Error("The variable foo is read-only"); }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, just define the "getter" (public function get), but NOT the "setter" (public function set). That way Flash will throw an error if someone tries to write to that property. No need to manually throw any errors, as put above.